# Idioms/Practices for Implementing Constrained Numeric Types in F#?

Tags: f#, refinement-type

Suppose one needs a numeric data type whose allowed values fall within a specified range. More concretely, suppose one wants to define an integral type whose min value is 0 and maximum value is 5000. This type of scenario arises in many situations, such as when modeling a database data type, an XSD data type and so on.

What is the best way to model such a type in F#? In C#, one way to do this would be to define a struct that implemented the range checking overloaded operators, formatting and so on. A analogous approach in F# is described here: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/

I don't really need though a fully-fledged custom type; all I really want is an existing type with a constrained domain. For example, I would like to be able to write something like

```
type MyInt = Value of uint16 where Value <= 5000 (pseudocode)
```

Is there a shorthand way to do such a thing in F# or is the best approach to implement a custom numeric type as described in the aforementioned blog post?

Comment: If you're looking for full-fledged value dependent types you might check out [F*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/fstar/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referring to what are called refinement types in type theory, and as pointed out by Daniel, look for [F*](http://rise4fun.com/FStar/tutorial/guide). But it is a research project.

As far as doing it with F#, in addition to Tomas' post, take a look at the [designing with types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html) series.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to implement a custom struct wrapping your data type (e.g., `int`), just as you would in C#.

The idea behind creating this custom struct is that it allows you to "intercept" all uses of the underlying data value *at run-time* and check them for correctness. The alternative is to check all of these uses at *compile-time*, which is possible with something like F* (as others mentioned), although it's much more difficult and not something you would use for everyday code.

Comment: How would that work since a struct has a default constructor which allows validation to be bypassed?

Comment: Others members of the struct -- e.g., custom operators -- should validate the struct as well. So if you use the default value for the struct, you won't immediately know it's invalid, but you'll find out the first time you use the value.

Comment: That seems strange since the point of defining a type is to ensure certain guarantees about the data.

Comment: Maybe so, but sometimes you have to make compromises in practice. With this technique, you still get those guarantees -- the compromise is that you potentially won't know right away when the type's invariants are violated. I find that as long as you know this possibility exists when you start writing the code, I'm extra careful about making sure no default values can find their way into the core code.