# Types to represent a mathematical interval

Tags: .net, types, f#, intervals

I often see functions with signature such as:

```
let f (lower: int) (upper: int) =
    //...
```

where `lower` and `upper` represent an upper and lower bound of some range that the function is going to operate on. What is missing from this type signature is information about whether the upper and lower bounds are inclusive or exclusive. On a good day that information will be in the documentation...

It seems to me that it would be much nicer to have type(s) to represent a [mathematical interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) so that APIs could specify the exact kind of interval, and callers would get compile errors if they failed to provide it. I've tried searching for such an implementation, but haven't come up with anything, hence this question to see if anyone knows of a suitable implementation. I'd like one that can be used from a .NET language, but other implementations that I could borrow ideas from would also be useful.

Ideally the design should allow the function signatures shown below. The { } contain the interval spec in standard interval notation - this should be replaced with the relevant types:

```
let f1 (interval: { [,] }) = // inclusive lower and upper bounds
    //..

let f2 (interval: { (,) }) = // exclusive lower and upper bounds
    //..

let f3 (interval: { [,) }) = // inclusive lower and exclusive upper bounds
    //..

let f4 (interval: { [∞,) }) = // infinite lower and exclusive upper bounds
    //..

let f5 (interval: { not empty }) = // a non-empty interval
    //..

let f6 (interval: { any interval }) = // accepts any kind of interval
    //..
```

This problem is harder if we consider that the interval type should be generic on the data type, but for starters let's limit it to a non-generic variant that one works for a single data type (e.g. ints or doubles or dates).

Clarification: I'm just asking if anyone knows of a library that provides such an implementation.

Comment: Apologies. I was hoping that someone could point me towards a library that provides such functionality. I'll add clarification to the question.

Comment: The question isn't about intervals but *constraints*. You 'll find that there are such concepts already. It's easier to specify them in F#. Languages like ADA and Eiffel even have these concepts baked in

Comment: @JohnPalmer I suspect you misunderstood the question. This isn't about writing code or looking for a library at all. It's about defining types with value constraints that can be enforced by the language/compiler. F# *does* have units of measure. .NET *does* have constraints. Other languages even allow you to specify the valid value range when declaring a type

Comment: People that vote to close, vote *for a valid reason*. The close votes right now mean that you failed to understand a question about *types*. It's not tools or a lazy request for code

Comment: @Akash check [this similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788353/idioms-practices-for-implementing-constrained-numeric-types-in-f). You are looking for [refinement types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_(computing)#Refinement_types), which aren't supported by the .NET framework. C# doesn't have such support but you can use Code Contracts to emulate part of it. I think F# doesn't have them either. It has a lot in common with languages that *do* have refinement types though and googling for "F# refinement types" returns some research and OSS projects

Comment: @Carsten then more care is advised. . Remember the first rule of SO, "Be Nice". The OP is being polite even though English isn't his first language - the question is definitely verbose. The OP doesn't know the name used for the concept he describes. Contracts, constraints and refinements *are* valid concepts though. You can say that there are *duplicate* questions if you will

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos again: I did nothing - neither downvote nor vorted to close - and I think I am usually quite nice in the FP subcommunities ;) - **plus** I don't think he is looking for something like this - I think he is just looking for an plain-old-interval type - but anyway it's getting OT - have a nice day

Answer (score 6):

I have not seen any F# library doing something like this. I think this is a fairly complex question with no clear answer - it very much depends on what kind of operations you need to do with the intervals (e.g. do you have some functions that work for any intervals?)

If you just wanted to have different F# types for different kinds of intervals, you could define a lot of simple data types using something like this:

```
module Interval = 
  type InclIncl = InclIncl of int * int
  type InclExcl = InclExcl of int * int
  type InfExcl = InfExcl of int
```

Then each of your functions would take the corresponding type:

```
let f1 (Interval.InclIncl(a, b)) = 0
let f2 (Interval.InclExcl(a, b)) = 0
let f3 (Interval.InfExcl(a)) = 0
```

However, this means that you cannot write function that takes any interval. So in many scenarios, it might actually make more sense to have a single type representing "an interval" which can represent all of the cases:

```
type Boundary = 
  | Inclusive of int
  | Exclusive of int
  | Unbounded

type Interval = Boundary * Boundary
```

Comment: I see F7 is a research project that adds refinement types to F#, although it tries to do a lot more than range checking. Are there any concepts/techniques that could be used easily in the OP's question?

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for those two suggestions, but I'm really looking for something that combines them both.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd not heard of refinement types, but from the little I've read so far, they seem to be more about constraining numerical values. I'm not asking to be able to specify the interval [-5, 7) in the type system - I just want, for example, to be able to specify that a function will accept any interval of the form [a, b)